# Youtube Videos Are Not Playing in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, youtube

Well I saw youtube videos even yesterday. But now I see this message...

> your browser does not currently recognize any of the video formats available

Can anyone tell me how can I fix this in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: What,s your browser?
I use firefox37 and youtube play without flash, with html5 player.

Comment: There is no need to repeat an accepted answer in your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should install a package called "ubuntu-restricted-extras" with this command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Actually, installer offers to do it for you but you may have not checked it up. This package brings various parts that may be illegal in some countries, so they are kept out of installation images. This contains archievers, encryption software and media codecs.

Comment: Of cause I assume that browser is Firefox and you do not use Flash in youtube. You should have provided those clarifications.

Comment: Some background on what that package is would have been nice.

Answer (score 0):

as @Barafu said, you haven't given much information as to your setup.

i would suggest using the Google Chrome browser, and trying to enable HTML5 video playback in YouTube (rather than using Flash video)

try checking https://www.youtube.com/html5 to see if it is enabled in your current browser

Answer (score 0):

**Clear the browse cache**

The usual solution to all your problems.

In Chromium "settings > advanced > cookies and other site data"

Answer (score -1):

Did you run the software updater? It may have updated and caused some compatibility issues. Try to use the canonical browser. just search "browser" and there should be another browser. If that doesn't work, than look at updating flash player.